# Which interpolation technique should I use?

Tags: data-transformation, econometrics, missing-data, interpolation

I have an annual data set, but I have a few missing values in the series. I do not know which interpolation technique should I use to fill the missing values.

```
 X        Y
1973    45.75
1974    43
1975    40.41
1976    37.98
1977    35.71
1978    33.6
1979    31.65
1980    29.86
1981    28.23
1982    26.76
1983    25.45
1984    24.3
1985    23.31
1986    22.47
1987    21.8
1988    21.29
1989    20.94
1990    20.74
1991    20.71
1992    20.84
1993    21.13
1994    21.57
1995    22.18
1996    22.94
1997    23.87
1998    24.96
1999    26.2
2000    27.61
2001    29.17
2002    30.9
2003    32.78
2004    
2005    23.9
2006    22.3
2007    
2008    17.2
2009    
2010    
2011    12.4
2012
```

Comment: Why not linear interpolation?

Comment: Also, you have to take into account the possibility of discontinuity in 2004.

Answer (score 2):

As @Aksakal implies, caution is needed here.

These don't seem plausible data: else why does the first part of the series follow a quadratic? Data points are shown below in green and a quadratic regression as orange curve.

[image]

But let's go along with the fiction that this is factual. Locally any interpolant you might take seriously will be exactly linear or nearly so, but otherwise watch out. Any idea that linear interpolation is conservative is belied by its tendency to step boldly into the unknown with just a smidgen of encouragement.

Here one of several alternatives is piecewise cubic Hermite interpolation which is a MATLAB staple. [Documentation can be found here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html) A lucid explanation by Cleve Moler makes it easy to translate from that into other software (Stata in the case of the graph below). Start [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/16/splines-and-pchips/).

[image]

Suggested rules for extrapolation:

1. Don't.
2. Ask for subject-matter background. Even vague qualitative information can be crucial in knowing what to trust, what is exceptionally high or low, what might be expected in the future.
3. Compare different interpolants. Agreement doesn't guarantee truth, but disagreement counsels scepticism.
4. Also consider building a time series model. It might even help.

Note for Stata users: The linear interpolation here is naturally done using `ipolate`. The pchip method uses `pchipolate` from SSC.

Comment: I really liked this comment in your answer: ‘Any idea that linear interpolation is conservative is belied by its tendency to step boldly into the unknown with just a smidgen of encouragement.’

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer Thanks for the encouragement: we aim to please.

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer, that's some Oxford PhD level English. I'm still trying to understand what it means exactly.

Comment: Don't point that straight line: It can go off in any direction. (Oxford doctorates are all D.Phil., not that I have one.)

Comment: @NickCox, thanks. That makes a total sense. Without a good understanding of the nature of series, extrapolation is unreliable, linear or other.

Comment: @Aksakal Agreed, strongly. (And much less importantly and in case any one noticed, there are higher doctorates at Oxford too for honorary degrees and bodies of published work.)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing observations at crucial points: 2004 and 2012. Something has happened in 2004, that your series bent down. What's going to happen in 2012 isn't clear. You need to know something about the underlying process in order to come up with sensible interpolation for 2004 and extrapolation for 2012. Otherwise, the linear interpolation will be fine in other missing points.